# И осталось лишь твоё «прости» / «Прости»

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> И осталось лишь твоё «прости» / «Прости».

> Это «закрой свой рот!» / «Закрой свой рот!», чес слово, меня в безумение свело.

> Фраза, любимая самая у моего деда, — «котишки-соловьишки!» / «Котишки-соловьишки!».

> На вопрос «ты чё, немец?» «Ты чё, немец?» последовал ответ — нулевой.

> Нужна ля запятая в предложении  «у тебя есть, что ль, друзья(,) котом умеющие рисовать?» / «У тебя есть, что ль, друзья(,) котом умеющие рисовать?»?

> Меня твоё «как дела?» / «Как дела» вообще не ободряет.